# How to remove the white spaces between tags in XML

Tags: android, xml

I created an XML document using Java in my android application. I have to call a web service in my application and pass this XML as an argument there. But my problem is there created a white space between each tag in the XML.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

Element root = doc.createElement("subscriber");
doc.appendChild(root);

//creating child node for username
EditText txtusername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
subscriber[0]=String.valueOf(txtusername.getText());
Element UserName=doc.createElement("UserName");             
UserName.setTextContent(subscriber[0]);
root.appendChild(UserName);

//creating child node for PASSWORD 
EditText txtPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
subscriber[1]=String.valueOf(txtPassword.getText());
Element Password=doc.createElement("Password");
Password.setTextContent(subscriber[1]);
root.appendChild(Password);

//set up a transformer
TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

//create string from xml tree
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
trans.transform(source, result);
String xmlString =sw.toString();

url = new URL("http://192.168.70.14/NewsLetter/subscribing.php?register= " + xmlString);

conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"); 
dis = conn.getInputStream();
```

The XML is:

```
<subscriber> <UserName>miya</UserName> <Password>today</Password> </subscriber>
```

Please give the solution for how to remove the white spaces between the `UserName` and `Password` tags.

Comment: <subscriber> <UserName>miya</UserName> <Password>today</Password> </subscriber>

Comment: It looks like you are feeding your XML document as input for an XSLT transformation. There are several ways for dealing with white space only text nodes in XSLT. Please, retag and post your stylesheet, so we can help you.

Answer (score 20):

Of course, it depends on your XML itself. However, you could try using regular expressions.

As an example:

```java
yourXmlAsString.replaceAll(">[\\s\r\n]*<", "><");
```

Would remove all whitespace between every XML element.

Comment: When I use the above regular expression, it shows an error: Inavalide regular expression

Comment: the regex should be ">[\\s\\r\\n]*<" (i.e. \r, \n should be escaped too

Answer (score 8):

Method [`documentBuilderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(boolean)) controls whitespace creation. Use this before you create a `DocumentBuilder`.

```
dbfac.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
```

Comment: Does this hold when exporting the XML document, or when parsing the XML string ? (in my case it did not help to overcome problems when parsing XML and whitespace creates nodes I do not want)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to remove whitespace/tabs/newlines from my transformation using the following property:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
```

You had it set to yes. I'm sure this question is old enough that it doesn't matter now; but if anyone runs into this in the future, setting the property to *no* saved me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the regular expression `(?:>)(\s*)<`

When you use it in the code for Java use 
`"(?:>)(\\s*)<"` and replace with `"><"`

```
String xmlString = "<note>    <to>Tove</to>    <from>Jani</from <heading>Reminder</heading> <title>Today</title>    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>    </note>";

String str = xmlString.replaceAll("(?:>)(\\s*)<", "><");
```

This will remove the spaces between the tags and maintain the spaces for the value.

Input:

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading> <title>Today</title>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Output:

```
<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><title>Today</title><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me. I had to use the below code, to remove both additional whitespaces and new lines.

```
xmlString.trim().replace("\n", "").replaceAll("( *)<", "<")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, thank you. As a caveat, although this is actually useful for my purpose, I noticed that it can also remove text content if that consists *only* of whitespace. For example, running the following:

```
String xmlIn = "<tag> </tag> <tag>\t</tag>\t <tag>\r\n</tag><tag> text </tag>";
String xmlOut = xmlIn.replaceAll("(?:>)(\\s*)<", "><");
System.out.println(xmlOut);
```

gives the following:

```
<tag></tag><tag></tag><tag></tag><tag> text </tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of all nodes in a document, and trims the nodeValue of each node if it exists.

```js
const copyChildrenNodesWithoutWhiteSpace = (document) => {
  const clone = document.cloneNode();

  for (const child of document.childNodes) {
    const childCopy = copyChildrenNodesWithoutWhiteSpace(child);
    clone.appendChild(childCopy);

    if (childCopy.nodeValue) {
      childCopy.nodeValue = childCopy.nodeValue.trim();
    }
  }

  return clone;
};

const result = copyChildrenNodesWithoutWhiteSpace(anyDocument);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.