# To trim the lines in a file in PI

Tags: java, bufferedreader, sap-pi, sap-xi

I have to trim the lines from the input file and generate the output in SAP PI. This can't be done using graphical mapping in SAP PI, so I use Java and build the code in Eclipse.

I had used `BufferedReader` to build the logic and it was working fine.. But as the XML file comes into SAP PI, I changed `BufferedReader` to `TransformerFactory` and I'm stuck here.

```
public class TestIntegrate {
    private Document doc = null;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileInputStream fin;
        
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/xyz/workspace/TEST_2.xml");
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("D:\\ProgramFiles\\eclipse\\mapping\\poslogoutput.xml");
            TestIntegrate t = new TestIntegrate();
            t.execute(fin, fout);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void execute(InputStream sourceFile, OutputStream targetFile) /*throws StreamTransformationException*/ {
        try {
            // Creating the parser object.
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = dBuilder.parse(sourceFile);
            
            writeOutputfile(doc, targetFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // End of execute 
    // Write to the output file 
    private void writeOutputfile(Document doc, OutputStream targetFile) {
        try {
            String lineToRemove = "<Tax>";
            String lineToRemove1 = "</Tax>";
            String currentLine;
            TransformerFactory transformFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            Transformer transformer = transformFactory.newTransformer();
            Writer outWriter = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(targetFile);
            transformer.transform(source, result);
            
            // Logic to trim the lines
            while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) /* ERROR: no reader object */ {
                String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                if (trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove) || trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove1)) continue;
                outWriter.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            
            System.out.println("File saved!");
            reader.close(); //ERROR: no reader object
            writer.close(); //ERROR:no Writer object
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Input file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<School>
    <SSLC>
        <name />
        <rollno />
    </SSLC>
    <PUC>
        <first_pu>
            <name />
            <rollno />
        </first_pu>
        <second_pu>
            <name />
            <rollno />
        </second_pu>
    </PUC>
    <PUC>
        <first_pu>
            <name />
            <rollno />
        </first_pu>
        <second_pu>
            <name />
            <rollno />
        </second_pu>
    </PUC>
    <PUC>
        <first_pu>
            <name />
            <rollno />
        </first_pu>
        <second_pu>
            <name />
            <rollno />
        </second_pu>
    </PUC>
</School>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not define `reader`.

Comment: @ Mr. Polywhirl Thanks for the reply... actually i have to remove reader as I am using TransformerFactory.. Kindly  Suggest me what to add in place of reader and Writer..

Comment: Can you provide a small example input and output file?

Comment: If you are reading an XML file, once you have the DOM, you can loop over the Elements/Nodes and trim their text value. Refer to: [*Stack Overflow: Strip whitespace and newlines from XML in Java*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11703766/1762224).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip whitespace and newlines from XML in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703635/strip-whitespace-and-newlines-from-xml-in-java)

Comment: input file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<School>  
<SSLC>  
 <name></name>    
 <rollno></rollno>  
</SSLC>
<PUC>
 <first_pu>
  <name></name>
  <rollno></rollno>
 </first_pu>
 <second_pu>
  <name></name>
  <rollno></rollno>
 </second_pu>

</PUC>
<PUC>
 <first_pu>
  <name></name>
  <rollno></rollno>
 </first_pu>
 <second_pu>
  <name></name>
  <rollno></rollno>
 </second_pu>

</PUC>
<PUC>
 <first_pu>
  <name></name>
  <rollno></rollno>
 </first_pu>
 <second_pu>
  <name></name>
  <rollno></rollno>
 </second_pu>

</PUC>
</School>

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl  But from where to call Trim().. Little confusion..:)

Comment: @user3497375 please edit your original question and paste the xml there instead of in a comment.

Comment: @Emz: Well, 2 hours later... I decided to add the input file from the comments.