# How to let Java.xml.Transformer output a xml without any useless space or line break?

Tags: java, xml, jaxp

My Code Now:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.StringWriter;

private String getStringByJAXP(Node input) {
        StreamResult xmlOutput;
        try {
            xmlOutput = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
            transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
            transformer.transform(new DOMSource(input), xmlOutput);
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return xmlOutput.getWriter().toString();
    }
```

Output:

```
<aaa>
    <a>text a</a>
    <b>
        <c>text c</c>
    </b>
    <f>
        <g><h a="xxx"/></g>
    </f>
</aaa>
```

But I want to output as follows:

```
<aaa><a>text a</a><b><c>text c</c></b><f><g><h a="xxx" /></g></f></aaa>
```

Notice that I can't do that task by some simple string replaces, because the space in `<a>text a</a>` shouldn't be replaced(`<a>texta</a>` is total different from `<a>text a</a>`).

EDIT:

`OutputKeys.INDENT, "no"` not works. Updated code:

```
private String getStringByJAXP(Node input) {
    StreamResult xmlOutput;
    try {
        xmlOutput = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(input), xmlOutput);
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return xmlOutput.getWriter().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar case once.
I tried *transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,"no");* first, but this did not work.
The problem was that my original node had additional "new line" text nodes.

The answer to [Strip whitespace and newlines from XML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703635/strip-whitespace-and-newlines-from-xml-in-java) fixed it for me. Basically, you just remove the unnecessary text nodes before you transform the parent node.

I ended up using this:

```
public static void trimWhitespace(Node node)
{
    NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
    for(int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); ++i) {
        Node child = children.item(i);
        if(child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            child.setTextContent(child.getTextContent().trim());
        }
        trimWhitespace(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are 4 answer in`The answer to Strip whitespace and newlines from XML in Java fixed it for me`...

Comment: It might be best to try get an original Node without the unnecessary text nodes though, if that is possible. In my case, this was impossible, and I don't think in such case, there is any other solution than removing these unnecessary nodes manually.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass an XSLT stylesheet to your Transformer which has the advantage that you will not have to parse your document twice.

```
InputStream xsltStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("trim-whitespace.xslt");
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltStream));
```

**trim-whitespace.xslt**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- copy all elements as they are -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*/text()[not(normalize-space())]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```