# Need to remove white space between two tags with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a bit of XML that I would like to strip the outer white space from.  As a preface:  The output is not well formed xml, it's a propritary spec I am relegated to dealing with.

The sample is:

```
<mattext>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>more text</span>
 </mattext>
```

What I need is:

```
<mattext><span>A</span>
  <span>more text</span></mattext>
```

Where all white space between the opening `<mattext>` and the first bit of inner content is gone, and the same for the closing `</mattext>`.

I've tried:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"<mattext>*<", "<mattext>", 
             RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

But I'm not having any luck.  Can anyone advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"<mattext>\s*<", "<mattext><", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: This seems to be the most direct approach to handle my specific need.

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=<mattext>)\s*|\s*(?=</mattext>)", "");
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/cE9yT4)

`(?<=<mattext>)` is a positive lookbehind and makes sure there is `<mattext>` before the spaces and newlines.

`(?=</mattext>)` is a positive lookahead and makes sure there is `</mattext>` after the spaces and newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Jerry's answer, with additional guard to ensure `<mattext>` is at start of input and `</mattext>` is at end.

```
Regex.Replace(input,
  @"(?:(?<=^\<mattext\>)[^\<]*)|(?:[^\>]*(?=\</mattext\>$))",
  string.Empty,
  RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not whitespace, It's \r or \n or even both \r\n

Comment: It's more than just that.  A simple \r\n replace leaves quite a bit of white space.

Comment: ok so the source is outside of your control is it?
Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274524/how-to-remove-the-white-spaces-bteween-tags-in-xml