# How to remove white spaces before xml nodes in C#

Tags: c#, xml

could anyone please help me on how to remove all the white spaces between XML tags as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

To:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

Need xml nodes in different lines but spaces before xml nodes should not be there

Comment: Why would you do this? It has no influence on how you navigate through the nodes.  Which can be done through xpath or XMLStreamer.

Comment: Yes correct But i have an old xml which has no spaces. To compare with the old xml we need that.

Comment: Makes no sense. The correct way to compare two xml is two streamthrough each element and compare their elements and attributes. A hacked way of doing it is by removing whitespace between a > and < which should be possible with a regex command. Check this post out for instance:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274524/how-to-remove-the-white-spaces-between-tags-in-xml

Answer (score 3):

### Using Regex

If you have loaded your xml into a string you can try doing it this way, but I hate and have an absolute disdain for regex so I wont guarantee that this gives you what you want.

```
string x = " <Hello>text </Hello>   <itsAme>";
string Replace1 = ">\\s+";
string Replace2 = "\\s+<";

x=Regex.Replace(x, Replace1 , ">");
x=Regex.Replace(x, Replace2, "<");
```

### Using XDocument

I recommend using @Martin Milan's answer. You can do it thusly. But instead set the SaveOptions to DisableFormatting to remove all whitespace. And should give you a single line, that should be easily comparable with your other xml file.

```
string x = " <Hello>   <ItsAMe>  </ItsAMe>   </Hello>  ";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(x, LoadOptions.None);
x = xDoc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the XDocument class from System.XML.Linq will do this for you. Both the Save and ToString method support a SaveOptions argument. Setting this to None should get you the results you're after...

Answer (score 0):

Do you write it using XmlSerializer?

Use **XmlWriterSettings** specifying **String.Empty** as **IndentChars**, you have several options; e.g.:

```
XmlWriterSettings **ws** = new XmlWriterSettings();
ws.CloseOutput = true;
ws.Indent = true;
ws.IndentChars = "";
ws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
ws.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize;
ws.NewLineOnAttributes = false;
```

Writing it to file...

```
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    using (XmlWriter wr = XmlWriter.Create(writer, **ws**))
    {
        // Namespace?
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        serializer.Serialize(wr, o, ns);
    }
    writer.Close();
}
```